# DOM How can I get element's position in "queue"

Tags: javascript, html

when I've got

```
<div id="wrap">
    <ul>
         <li class='first'><img src="something.jpg"></li>
         <p>this would be problem in finding next li</p>
         <li><img src="somethingelse.jpg"></li>
         <li><img src="somethingother.jpg"></li>
         <li><img src="image.jpg"></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

how can I get li's element position in ul (parent) node resp. element using javascript (if it would help, I'm using `querySelectorAll`). Is there any property? I want to get next element using something like jQuery:

```
$('.first').next('li');
```

If I'd use `.next()` it will return `nextElementSibling` which is `<p>` element.
So I managed to do something like this:

```
function contains( stack, element ) {
    var res = [];
    // stack would be object (for example NodeList)
    // element is object that is gonna be found
    for ( var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++ ) {
         // do the same for className, nodeName .....
         if ( stack[i]['id'] == element ) {
              push.call( res, stack[i] );
         }
    }

    return res;
}
```

and then I call my Object function called `.originate()` which creates an instance of my library and put all of found matches elements to be able use Library methods on it.

So stack is object of elements with all the properties as qSA returns.
When I call `cba.next('li')` it will find all the child elements in cba's parent element (cba is "callbacked" element through `.map()`) that matches `element` arg in `.find()` and I need to compare these child elements with `cba` and if it is `'li'` (as we are looking for), return `i + 1` element (which is actually next element if matches).

Comment: It's not a valid HTML, i think

Comment: Sadly, it is, according to a quick test.

Comment: Okay, doesn't matter. It's an example of problem.

Answer (score 1):

try using the new `matches()` method:

```
function next(elm, sel) {
    while(elm = elm.nextElementSibling) if(elm.matches(sel)) return elm;
}
```

usage:

```
var elm= document.querySelector(".first");
next( elm, "li").innerHTML="HIT!!!";
```

live demo http://pagedemos.com/gbkzrde36a5g/

you can polyfill and/or use prefix version for backwards compat, or just check the `elm.tagName` if that's all you care about.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, getting the `li` following `ul > li.first`, turns out to be this:

`$('ul > li')
 .get(
   $('ul > li')
   .index( 
     $('ul > li.first')
   )
   + 1
 )
)`

This

```
$('ul > li.first').next()`
```

does not work, because `.next` retrieves the element index from the DOM.

Neither does this, for some reason:

```
$('ul > li').parent().find('li.first').next()`
```

However, this does, where we get `n`:

```
var s =  $('ul > li'),    
    l = s.parent().find('li.first'),
    i = s.index( l ),
    n = s.get( i + 1 );
```

```js
var s =  $('ul > li'),    
    l = s.parent().find('li.first'),
    i = s.index( l ),
    n = s.get( i + 1 );

$(
 $('ul > li')
 .get(
   $('ul > li')
   .index( 
     $('ul > li.first')
   )
   + 1
 )
)
.css({color:'red'})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <ul>
         <li class='first'>first</li>
         <p>this would be problem in finding next li</p>
         <li class='second'>second</li>
         <li>third</li>
         <li>fourth</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```